# Удалить комментарии из программы на языке Си

Tags: c, комментарии

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с одним косяком в этой программе... Проблема в том, что **многострочные** комментарии не удаляются, а по идее должны...

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

const int N=100;

void main ()
{
char symbol;
char symbol_temp;
char input_name[N], output_name[N];
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

printf ("Введите название входного файла! \n");
scanf ("%s", &input_name);
printf ("\n");

FILE *input_file=fopen(input_name, "r+");

if(input_file == NULL) 
{ 
    printf("Ошибка открытия файла.\n\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf ("Введите название выходного файла! \n");
scanf ("%s", &output_name);
printf ("\n");

FILE *output_file=fopen(output_name, "w");

if(output_file == NULL) 
{ 
    printf("Ошибка создания файла.\n\n");
    exit(1);
}

while (!feof(input_file))
{
    symbol=fgetc(input_file);
    if (symbol=='"')
    {
        do
        {
            fprintf(output_file,"%c", symbol);
            symbol = fgetc(input_file);
        }
        while ( (symbol!='"')&&(!feof(input_file)) );
    }
    else
    {
        if (symbol == '/')
        {
            symbol = fgetc(input_file);
            if (symbol == '/')
            {
                {
                    do
                    {
                        symbol = fgetc(input_file);
                    }
                    while ((symbol!='\n')&&(!feof(input_file)));
                    fprintf(output_file,"%c",'\n');
                    continue;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (symbol == '*')
                {
                    symbol_temp=fgetc(input_file);
                    do
                    {
                        symbol=symbol_temp;
                        symbol_temp=fgetc(input_file); 
                    }
                    while ( (symbol!='*')&&(symbol_temp!='/')&&(!feof(input_file)) );
                    continue; 
                }

                else
                {
                    fprintf(output_file,"%c", '/');
                    fprintf(output_file,"%c", symbol);
                }
            }
        }
    }
if (!feof(input_file)) fprintf(output_file,"%c",symbol);
}

fclose(input_file);
fclose(output_file);
}
```

Текст, на котором я тестирую. Текст после цифры **4** и до цифры **6** остается, хотя должен удаляться. На программу смотрю - вроде все верно, вроде должно выполняться... Код вроде элементарный..(

```
int main (void)
{
setlocale (LC_ALL,"Russian");   
////////////////////////////
1
\\//\\\///\\//\\\;
2
"/////////"
// kojdlfkerf
3
"/* kkkk */" //slkj
4
/*
khg
dmflkdms
fvsd
kf;sd;l
////////piouhjkl
5
    sxsalkxas
    //
    */
    6
    \
//  system ("pause");
    7
}
```

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал регулярные выражения.

Comment: А вы про конструкцию "else if" слышали? =)

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал state machine, иначе вам трудно будет разобраться с конструкциями вида

    /* // */
    // /*

и т. п.

Comment: А что такое "state machine"?

И "регулярные выражения"?

Я только новичок, так что извините за дурацкие вопросы...(

Comment: Регулярные выражения это супер-пупер парсер любого текста в котором известна четкая структура.

Comment: @ReinRaus: с вас тоже пример кода :)

Comment: @VladD, завтра :)  
Надо узнать такие аспекты как:  
возможен ли перенос строки между ограничителями строчных значений  
возможен ли перенос строк внутри конструкций:  

    x=5/
    4;
например валидный код ?  
И.Т.П.

Comment: @ReinRaus, разрывать строки и символы нельзя, но если экранировать перенос строки бэкслешем, то можно. Например:

    const char *p = "ac\
    d"
      /* это
         строка "acd\"
      */
    "\
    \\";
    char x='\
    \''; // а это один апостроф

Уверены, что регулярками такое можно корректно разобрать?

Comment: @avp: современные регулярки являются Тьюринг-полными, но написание парсера для сложного языка на них всё равно геморрой, как мне кажется. Вот, например, правильный парсер HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/276994

Comment: @VladD, насколько уловил, на перле. А вот цитата оттуда же

    "And trying to do so is a terrible waste of time, because good  parsing classes exist which you should use for this task. The right  answer to people trying to parse arbitrary HTML is not that it is impossible. That is a facile and disingenuous answer. The correct and honest answer is that they shouldn’t attempt it because it is too much of a bother to figure out from scratch; they should not break their back striving to reïnvent a wheel that works perfectly well."

Но на самом деле, я не понял, как этим разбором воспользоваться.

Comment: @VladD, а почему Вы уверены, что ответ на SO действительно верный? 

Автор так написал? 

--

На самом деле для  подобных вещей должны быть наборы тестов (как для структуры e-mail MIME для IMAP). И кстати, очень многие (в т.ч. Outlook Express (не помню, какую версию пробовал)) программы их не проходят.

Comment: @avp: Угу, на перле. Там определяются все синтаксические конструкции HTML, и можно, поправив код, дописать собственные "обработчики", которые будут вызываться, как только соответствующая конструкция встретится, если я правильно понял. Это позволяет легко решать  задачи типа "найти все ссылки" или "найти последний элемент списка внутри тега с id=abcd" и т. п.

---
Если вы ещё не видели, посмотрите на [этот ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/276994), чистая поэзия в стиле Лавкрафта.

Comment: @avp: это же [Том Кристиансен](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Christiansen), автор одной из лучших книг по Перлу, и один из разработчиков самого Перла. Он замечательный программист, не имею оснований не верить ему. (Впрочем, парсер легко проверить, и если бы проверка не прошла, зубры на SO заклевали бы ответ.)

---
Автор пишет, что проверил на сотне тысяч HTML-файлов, плюс на специальных файлах, сконструированных так, чтобы обманывать примитивные парсеры.

Comment: Извините, что не на Си, а на PHP- сами понимаете что смысл не в языке, а в PCRE  
http://ideone.com/nm8RwW  
Текст из вопроса обработан корректно, написано за 3-4 минуты (интересно было бы узнать за сколько был написан код из вопроса на Си).

Comment: @ReinRaus: вроде правильно, контрпримеров не нашёл, классно! Единственная небольшая проблема -- `int/**/main` превращается в `intmain`, хотя должно в `int main` (многострочный комментарий заменяется на пробел).

Comment: Кстати, и мой, и ваш парсер неверно с точки зрения языка C обрабатывает такую конструкцию:

    '\"'//comment"

(это должно трактоваться как символ `"` с последующим комментарием). Поправил свой код.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, а почему эта штука определяется не как комментарий?

      *'\'\////*

(Последние пять символов имею ввиду...)

http://s54.radikal.ru/i145/1303/d5/eeeb5eaf8717.png

Comment: @777Julia777, а где Вы видите в:

    *'\'\////*

комментарий?

После `*` стоит апостроф (`'`), т.е начинается значение символьной константы (char). `\'` это собственно код апострофа, а дальше идет всякая ерунда (это ошибка, очевидно завершающий константу апостроф просто не написан, компилятор обругается), но завершающего константу апострофа нет, поэтому о комментарии речь не идет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас неправильное условие выхода из цикла:

```
while ( (symbol!='*')&&(symbol_temp!='/')&&(!feof(input_file)) )
```

Нужно так:

```
while ( !((symbol == '*') && (symbol_temp == '/')) && (!feof(input_file)) )
```

---

В вашем текущем коде есть и другие недостатки.

Те, которые сразу бросились в глаза:

1. Вы не определяете escape-символы в строке, так что вот такая конструкция:

   char *s = ""//";

ошибочно распознается как комментарий.

2. Получив символ `'/'`, вы не проверяете конец файла.

---

Для таких простых случаев, как у вас, лучше использовать парсер на state-machine.

Идея в том, что вы обрабатываете один символ за раз, а для того, чтобы правильно его обрабатывать в различных ситуациях, используете *состояние*. Состояние часто кодируют номером, но можно просто кодировать указателем на функцию, реализующую логику этого состояния.

Вот пример для вашего кода:

```
typedef void Parser(char, FILE *);
Parser* currentParser;

void InStringParser(char c, FILE *output_file);
void InCharParser(char c, FILE *output_file);
void AfterSlashParser(char c, FILE *output_file);
void InInlineCommentParser(char c, FILE *output_file);
void InMultilineCommentParser(char c, FILE *output_file);

void NormalParser(char c, FILE *output_file)
{
    switch (c)
    {
    case '\"':
        currentParser = InStringParser;
        break;
    case '\'':
        currentParser = InCharParser;
        break;
    case '/':
        currentParser = AfterSlashParser;
        // no need to print
        return;
    }
    fprintf(output_file, "%c", c);
}

bool inStringLastEscape = false;
void InStringParser(char c, FILE *output_file)
{
    fprintf(output_file, "%c", c);
    if (c == '\"' && !inStringLastEscape)
        currentParser = NormalParser; // inStringLastEscape will be false
    inStringLastEscape = (c == '\\') && !inStringLastEscape;
}

bool inCharLastEscape = false;
void InCharParser(char c, FILE *output_file)
{
    fprintf(output_file, "%c", c);
    if (c == '\'' && !inCharLastEscape)
        currentParser = NormalParser; // inCharLastEscape will be false
    inCharLastEscape = (c == '\\') && !inCharLastEscape;
}

void AfterSlashParser(char c, FILE *output_file)
{
    switch(c)
    {
    case '/':
        currentParser = InInlineCommentParser;
        return;
    case '*':
        currentParser = InMultilineCommentParser;
        return;
    default:
        currentParser = NormalParser;
        fprintf(output_file, "/%c", c);
    }
}

bool inInlineLastEscape = false;
void InInlineCommentParser(char c, FILE *output_file)
{
    if (c == '\n' && !inInlineLastEscape)
    {
        fprintf(output_file, "\n");
        currentParser = NormalParser;
    }
    inInlineLastEscape = (c == '\\') && !inInlineLastEscape;
}

bool inMultilineLastStar = false;
void InMultilineCommentParser(char c, FILE *output_file)
{
    if (c == '/' && inMultilineLastStar)
    {
        fprintf(output_file, " ");
        currentParser = NormalParser; // inMultilineLastStar will be false
    }
    inMultilineLastStar = (c == '*');
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // открыть файлы и всё такое

    currentParser = NormalParser;

    char symbol;
    while ((symbol = fgetc(input_file)) != EOF)
        currentParser(symbol, output_file);

    fclose(input_file);
    fclose(output_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: VladD, спасибо большое !!! Все заработало!
Теперь все понятно)

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую в этом разобраться...

Comment: @777Julia777: Пожалуйста! Попробуйте пройти код из моего примера под отладчиком, и посмотреть, как меняется переменная `currentParser`, должно стать ясно.

Comment: Внес в выражение поправки:  
обработку char `'\"'`  
замена многострочного комментария на пробел (работает только если справа от комментария в тексте есть пробел, иначе просто удалится

Comment: @VladD, Ваша программа не отрабатывает `\\n` в однострочном комментарии.

Дальше тестировать не стал.

Comment: @avp: Точно, не находило, поправил. Спасибо!

Comment: @ReinRaus: А где ваш новый вариант? В этом: <http://ideone.com/nm8RwW> что-то не так, потому что `int/**/main` должно превращаться в `int main`, а превращается в `intmain`. Или это by design? (Вставлять пробел всегда правильнее, потому что так ведёт себя препроцессор C.)

Comment: @VladD, негде пробел взять в такой строке :)  
Нужно либо callback писать для замены, либо добавлять пробел в строку- хотелось ограничиться простой строкой замены вроде `$1$2$3$4`. Но раз компилятор всегда вставляет пробел, то и я сделаю так.

Comment: @ReinRaus: последний вариант работает, спасибо!

Comment: @777Julia777, комментирую здесь (по цифрам 4-6 измененного вопроса), т.к. к меня под Вашим вопросом лимит комментариев закончен.

--

Действительно, должен удаляться. И программа @VladD его удаляет. А вот Вашего кода мы не видим, поэтому подсказать не получится.

Comment: Немного запоздал :) но очень интересуют некоторые моменты. 1) В Если в фале будет строчка например "`/123/123`", то на выходе вашего кода мы получим "`/1/2/3`", то есть перед каждым символом ставится `/`, а когда встречается другой `/` рассматривается уже как комментарий. Я думаю в `default` нужно наверно добавить строчку `currentParser = NormalParser` это хоть и не правильная строка, но и не комментарий. Может ошибаюсь. 2) Зачем вы вносили правку в функцию `InInlineCommentParser`? Вот вообще не понял.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков: По поводу 1), я исправил как вы и сказали, теперь код работает как надо. Проверял на примере `int x = 1/123/123; char* y = "/123/123";`. Если что-то ещё работает не так, виноват, исправлю :)

Comment: @ПавелЕриков: А там правка для случая, когда строка-комментарий завершается бэкслешем. В этом случае перевод строки как бы заэкранирован, и следующая строка тоже считается продолжением комментария.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков: Как-то так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O8xG.png

Comment: @VladD ого, не знал о таких комментариях.