# Программа удаляющая комментарии C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки, конечные-автоматы

> "Напишите программу, которая удаляет все комментарии из программы на С++. Это значит,надо читать символы из `cin` и удалять комментарии двух видов: `//` и `/* */`. Получившийся текст запишите в cout. Не заботьтесь о красивом виде получившегося текста(это уже другая,более сложная задача). Корректность программ неважна. Нужно учитывать возможность появления символов `//` `/*` и `*/` в комментариях,строках и символьных константах."

*- Задачка из книжки Бьерна Страуструпа.*

Вопросы:

1. Как читать символы из cin, если этот оператор после пробела не принимает дальше текст?
2. Как бы вы реализовали логику? Сразу на ум приходит `if (ch[i] = '/' && ch[i+1] = '/')`, но такой вариант будет стирать бэкслэши и из строк("") в том числе. Как исправить этот косяк?

Comment: Можно считать количество ковычек(") ,тогда если их кол-во нечетное,то программа будет делать вывод,что ковычки открыты в данный момент и не будет стирать бэкслэши в них..но это больше похоже на какой-то костыль.

Comment: Про кавычки: только так и надо, есть еще кавычки в строках `str = "text with\"quote\"";`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Удалить комментарии из программы на языке Си](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/205788/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%a1%d0%b8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Ну, вам же пишут - "*надо читать символы из `cin`*" - так почему бы не использовать функцию посимвольного чтения [`get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)? По-моему, намек более чем очевиден.
2. Самая простая логика - [детерминированный конечный автомат](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82) :) Вводим переменную состояния, принимающую значения (хоть перечисление :)) - обычный текст, предкомментарий, комментарий (2 шт.), строка, символьная константа. Можно еще некоторые промежуточные состояния - будет легче работать. Дальше - при прочтении одного символа (надо еще хранить предыдущий) работаем примерно так (набросок, надо поточнее) -

Мы в основном состоянии. Это кавычка? Предыдущий - `\`? просто выводим их. Нет? Переходим в состояние строки, выводим, идем дальше. Это начало комментария? Переходим в состояние предкомментария, символ запоминаем. Это просто обычный символ? запомнить, вывести.

Мы в состоянии предкомментария. Это слеш или звездочка? Если да - игнорируем символ, переходим в состояние комментария. Если нет - переходим в основное состояние, идем в обработку символа в основном состоянии, сохраненный выводим...

Мы в состоянии строки. Это кавычка? Да - переходим в основное состояние. Символ выводим в любом случае...

Мы в состоянии комментария `//`. Это символ новой строки? переходим в основное состояние, символ выводим. Нет - символ игнорируем.

Ну, и так далее - все возможные состояния и символы. Распишите картинку с переходами - вам сразу все станет понятнее... Да, она не самая простая, но и не такая уж и сложная.